# JS Dropdown button content not appearing where it should

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu for each use post which will allow user's to share/save/delete posts listed on the site.
Regardless of which post dropdown menu I click, the dropdown menu content always appears under the post at the top of the page. (see picture below code)
How can I fix this to show the associated dropdown per post?

**HTML and JS inside PHP Echo**

```
<div class="postBox">
                        <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                        <a class="postusername" href="../user?page='.$UserName.'">'.$UserName.'</a>
                        <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
                        <p>'.$Text.'<p>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">···</button>
                            <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                                <a href="#about">About</a>
                                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                                <a href="#contact">4</a>
                                <a href="#contact">5</a>
                                <a href="#contact">6</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <script>
                        function myFunction() {
                            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
                        }

                        window.onclick = function(event) {
                            if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
                                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                                var i;
                                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
                                        openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
    .dropbtn {
    color: #c42222;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 50px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

[image: Dropdown Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `right: 0` from `dropdown-content` class.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle("show")
  // document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: #c42222;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 50px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="postBox">
                    <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                    <a class="postusername" href="../user?page='.$UserName.'">'.$UserName.'</a>
                    <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
                    <p>'.$Text.'<p>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">···</button>
                        <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#home">Home</a>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            <a href="#contact">4</a>
                            <a href="#contact">5</a>
                            <a href="#contact">6</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                    <a class="postusername" href="../user?page='.$UserName.'">'.$UserName.'</a>
                    <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
                    <p>'.$Text.'<p>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">···</button>
                        <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#home">Home</a>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            <a href="#contact">4</a>
                            <a href="#contact">5</a>
                            <a href="#contact">6</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                    <a class="postusername" href="../user?page='.$UserName.'">'.$UserName.'</a>
                    <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
                    <p>'.$Text.'<p>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">···</button>
                        <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#home">Home</a>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            <a href="#contact">4</a>
                            <a href="#contact">5</a>
                            <a href="#contact">6</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the issue where the top dropdown content always shows is still active.  
I need the dropdown content to appear under the clicked icon, but it's always under the top icon.

Comment: You are welcome, The code you provided already appears under the clicked icon, if you Run the code snippet, you will see that it appears under the clicked icon, Could you provide some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I have more than one post on my site, in the code snippet, it's just one post.  
When there are multiple, it will always show the dropdown content under the first post regardless if I clicked the 2nd 3rd or 4th dropdown icon.  This code is inside a while loop to iterate through each post in the db

Comment: Yes, I see, the issue in your code, is you are using the `myDropdown` `id` to toggle the `show` class, So whatever menu you click it will only show the first dropdown ( the `id` should be unique otherwise if you try to query it, you will get the first element that has this `id` which is the first dropdown )

Comment: I just update the answer, please check again.